# MP4 with 2 audio tracks

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to copy the second audio track from multiple .mp4 files to .wav files.
I found this script for .avi files :

```
@ECHO OFF
for %%a in (*.avi) do ffmbc -i "%%a" -vn -map 0:2:0:0:0:0 -acodec copy -f wav -y "%%~na".wav
```

I don't know anything about FFMPEG, so ... is there a way to do the same thing with .mp4 ?
Thanks.

Comment: did you try simply replacing `*.avi` with `*.mp4`? What you posted is a batch file where the first part from `for` to `do` is a batch command. The part after `do` is the program to run and any parameters. Google "batch file for do" for more information about batch, google "ffmbc documentation" for the rest

Comment: I already tried to simply replace .Avi with .mp4, but the output file is empty,  there is only some background noise.

Comment: you will need to examine the input file and check the map parameter probably.

Comment: Here is what I have in the map for every file : https://zenoo.tinytake.com/sf/MzQxMjA5XzE5ODU1ODY

Comment: check your map paramenter

Answer (score 0):

This example will output the second audio stream as PCM signed 16-bit little-endian audio in WAV:

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:a:1 output.wav
```

- The `0` is the input file index and `0` refers to the first input (and only input in this example).
- The `a` is a [stream specifier](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1) to select audio.
- The `1` is the stream index, and the `1` refers to the second audio stream.

See the [`-map` option documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using my [dmMediaConverter](http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html) which is a ffmpeg GUI. Select **bulk** mode, drag and drop the video files and make all the changes necesary (look in the screenshots) :***Video none***, **Subtitles none**, Audio - **Audio Tab** - use the settings from the audio tab where you choose the **wav codec** and also put **2 in nth** for the seccond stream, **wav** file extention. Then press **Add Job** and **Start** the queue. That's all. I hope that helps.
[image]
[image]
http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html